# Replacement for vim-vinegar in VS Code?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I've been using Vim for a while now and I'm trying out Visual Studio Code. One thing I have been missing a lot is the ability to navigate between files in the way that [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) enables.

Using this plugin in Vim, I can press `-` and be taken into a file browser, starting in the directory that the current file is in. Selecting a file opens it, and pressing `-` again traverses up a directory level.

Is there anything like this for VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can mostly be achieved by using breadcrumbs. [Here's some configuration that gets things pretty close](https://github.com/lencioni/dotfiles/commit/2357591c14616b15f40d6cabdfc7a526014a97db).

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. Still a far cry from actual vinegar, but a great improvement after 2 minutes of tweaking settings!